# Android cardView click callback

Tags: java, android, onclick, material-design, android-cardview

I am trying to use this library for card view
https://github.com/DenisMondon/material-design-library

```
<com.blunderer.materialdesignlibrary.views.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mdl_title="CardView"
        app:mdl_description="A Left Image CardView"
        app:mdl_normalButton="Normal"
        app:mdl_highlightButton="Highlight"
        app:mdl_imagePosition="left"
        app:mdl_image="@drawable/image" />
```

I can not figure out how to add a onClickListener for the labels normalButton and highlightButto.

Can someone please give me a hand. thank you

Also how to set an Image programmatically into this cardView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has following two listeners

```
private OnClickListener mOnNormalButtonClickListener;
private OnClickListener mOnHighlightButtonClickListener;
```

You need to implement `CardView.mOnNormalButtonClickListener, CardView.mOnHighlightButtonClickListener` in your activity and override their methods to implement the click listeners for these buttons and set them using these functions.

```
setOnNormalButtonClickListener(OnClickListener onNormalButtonClickListener)
setOnHighlightButtonClickListener(OnClickListener onHighlightButtonClickListener)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, Do you how set the image to this card programtily ?

Comment: You can use the following function for setting image programatically
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable imageDrawable)

Comment: To set the image from url , You will need to download it first preferably on background thread and then populate in the UI thread using the same method. For example you can see the code  here
http://javatechig.com/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android

Answer (score 1):

@Joolah

With the latest version of the library, you can have a cardview url image.
Just write this:

```
myCardView.setImageUrl("http://your_image_url");
```